# TypeError: startDate.getTime is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date());  
  
const apiCall = () => {
    let timeStamp = Number(startDate.getTime());

    axios.get(
        `https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=BTC&tsyms=BTC,USD,EUR&ts=${timeStamp}&extraParams=ProfitsCrypto`
      )
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data);
      });
 };
```

Hi there,
I have some problem with react, I trying to use `getTime` because I want a timestamp to use api,
I can use `console.log(startDate.getTime())` but it's error `TypeError: startDate.getTime is not a function.`

Can anybody help me?
Thank you.

Comment: Just a side note - `getTime()` returns a timestamp as a number so you don't need to parse it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must check what is the dataType of startDate variable when you are using it. I think its type or value is changing somewhere in the code. You should share your code instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing that error because the very moment you instantiate the `apiCall` closure function, the reference of `startDate` has not yet been initialized by `useState()` to your provided value `new Date()`.

The solution to this, is wrapping your `apiCall` method with a `useCallback()` [React hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback), and provide your value `startDate` as a dependency. This way, each time `startDate` value changes, your `apiCall` method will work as expected.

```js
const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date());  
  
const apiCall = useCallback(() => {
    let timeStamp = Number(startDate.getTime());

    axios.get(
        `https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=BTC&tsyms=BTC,USD,EUR&ts=${timeStamp}&extraParams=ProfitsCrypto`
      )
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data);
      });
 }, [startDate]); // note the dependency reference here
```